# IIS 7.5, need help to understand how app pool recycling works

Tags: iis-7.5, application-pools, iis

I am using windows server 2008 R2 to only host one application (asp.net mvc3).  The first time the initial page load was really slow.

In my app pool recycling setting, only "regular time intervals"(in minutes) is checked and the value is set to 1740.  If I understand  correctly, my app pool will be recycled every 29 hours. however, I noticed sometimes after a couple hours I go back to my web site, the page load is slow again. It seems like the  app pool got recycled.  this is the dev server, no traffic at all. Is it because there's no traffic so it recycles itself, even though the time intervals were set to 29 hrs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at the app pool's Advanced Settings, and under Process Model you probably have 'Idle Time-out (minutes)' set to 20.

If the site is not accessed for this amount of time, the app pool will shutdown, releasing it's resources back to the system.

Comment: thank you so much.  this is exactly what I am looking for. sorry I cannot vote it up, need at least 15 reputation to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Fiddler to analyze the web traffic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250446%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and see if you can identify where the bottlenecks exist. You might also want to consider using [Performance Monitor to watch RAM, CPU, and IO usage](http://www.it-etc.com/2010/04/14/use-perfmon-to-monitor-servers-and-find-bottlenecks/)...

If the server has even decent hardware, a decent network connection (100mbps is fine for your environment) then delivering one web site should be childs play. It's time to look at other factors.

Does your code make any DB calls? is that DB on the same server or another server?

Have you done anything to help [increase performance within IIS](https://msmvps.com/blogs/bernard/archive/2006/01/07/80510.aspx)?